# Why html elements are rendered in an unexpected order?

Tags: html, css

The following code with its output is also available in: https://jsfiddle.net/rupali317/rj4ashxq/

**Goal:** In the following code I am trying to create a workflow bar, showing step 1 , step 2 and so on.

**Expected results:** These steps are highlighted as green circular buttons and there should be blue arrows in between the circular green buttons.

**Actual result:**  As depicted in my fiddle, the arrow lines appear first, followed by the three circular buttons and finally the two arrow heads.

**Question:** I have clearly specified the order of the html elements (which should give me my expected results). Question is, why the ordering is happening differently?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .green-button {
      color: white;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0px;
      cursor: auto;
    }
    
    .arrow {
      width: 120px;
    }
    
    .line {
      margin-top: 25px;
      width: 110px;
      background: blue;
      height: 1px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .head {
      margin-top: 15px;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 10px solid blue;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="green-button">1</button>
    <span class="arrow">
        <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="head"></span>
    </span>
    <button class="green-button">2</button>
    <span class="arrow">
        <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="head"></span>
    </span>
    <button class="green-button">3</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float line in your css is going to force the line to appear to the left of the circles.

Try this:

```
.green-button {
          color: white;
          background-color: #27AE60;
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 50px;
          width: 50px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 0px;
          cursor: auto;
        }

        .arrow {
          width:120px;
        }

        .line {
          margin-top:25px;
          width:100px;
          padding:0 50px;
          height:1px;
          border-style:solid;
          border-width:1px;
          border-color:blue;
          background:blue;
        }

        .head {  
          margin-top:15px;
          border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
          border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
          border-left: 10px solid blue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `.arrow` display inline block. This will order your arrows as the expected result indicates

```
.arrow {
  width:120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

```css
.green-button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #27AE60;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  cursor: auto;
}

.arrow {
  width:120px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line {
  margin-top:25px;
  width:110px;
  background:blue;
  height:1px;
  float:left;
}

.head {  
  margin-top:15px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <button class="green-button">1</button>
   <span class="arrow">
    <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="head"></span>
   </span>
   <button class="green-button">2</button>
   <span class="arrow">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="head"></span>
   </span>
   <button class="green-button">3</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```